# How to create a B-Spline with QwtSpline

Tags: c++, qt, qwt, bspline

In QwtSpline there are two different types of splines, but I don't see a difference between both types.

I found a image, that explains my problem:
[image: "https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3cVJ.jpg"]

QwtSpline always creates a spline, like that on the left side of the picture.
But I want to have a Spline, like that one on the right side.

My Code is the following:

```
QwtSpline spline;
QPolygonF polygon;
QVector<QPointF> result;

polygon.append(startPoint);
polygon.append(rotatedPoint);
polygon.append(endPoint);

spline.setPoints(polygon);

for(double i = startPoint.rx(); i < endPoint.rx(); i++)
{
    result << QPointF(i, spline.value(i));
}
result << QPointF(endPoint.rx(), spline.value(endPoint.rx()));
```

What I want to do, is to draw a spline like that one on the right side of the picture to a QwtPlot. Maybe there is a easier way to solve my problem, than creating a QwtSpline iterate throug it to creat a QwtCurve with every point on the QwtSpline.

If it is easier, to draw a bezier curve to QwtPlot, that's no problem, a bezier curve would be easier for me. I only took a spline, because I didn't find a bezier curve in Qwt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Qwt from one of the branches >= 6.2. It has a complete new implementation of several spline interpolation algorithms.

But if it is about drawing a bezier curve only you can also use QwtShapeItem, what is displaying a QPainterPath. Of course you can also use QPainterPath to create a QPolygon from your bezier curve and then use QwtPlotCurve.

Comment: Thank you Uwe, it's not only about drawing the curve. But the problem is, that I can't use the Qwt version, I want. I have to use a defined version, because the Qwt library I am using is component of a bigger project. So far I don't know the exaclty verion of the Qwt library I am using. But I will try to find out.

Comment: If you have further questions better ask on the dedicated Qwt support channels. I don't check stackoverflow on a regular base.

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys because you didn't like my answer bevore, I will try to explain how to calculate a bezier curve:

I think the easiest way is to use the Bernstein-Bézier representation of curves.

To do that, you have to find out the Bernstein polynomials. That's not difficult. There is a formular to do that its[image]

n is the number of points of your curve and
i is the actually point.

That means that you have so many Bernstein polynom, how many points you have.

If you know every Bernstein polynom you are able to use the following formular to calculate the curve.
[image]

n is the total number of points and
i is the index of the current point.

P is a point and t always runs from 0 to 1. 0 is the positon at the left side and 1 represents the position on the right side. r is the new point of the curve.

Now you have two calculate the formular above for x and y.

This is the formular for x

[image]

This is the formular for y

[image]

As you can see the only variable parameter on the right side is t. That means, that you have to calculate this formular many times with t between 0 and 1. The easiest way to do that, is to write a for loop like that:

```
QList<QPointF> results = QList<QPointF>();
QList<QPointF> points = QList<QPointF>();
for(double i = 0; i <= 1; i+=0.01)
{
    double x = //formular for rx
    double y = //formular for ry
    results << QPointF(x, y);
}
```

I hope it wasn't to complicated. If you didn't understand this short explanation, you can look at the Handbook of Mathematics. In the Sixth Edition its on site 1000 to 1001.

ISBN: 978-3-662-46220-1